# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как переделать код

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Всем доброго времени суток! Имеется код

```
const unsigned char *buffer[]={0x06,0x10};
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:sizeof(buffer)];
```

После его выполнения в data содержится 06000000 10000000. Как сделать чтобы содержалось 06 10? Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Ваш вопрос целит ровно в ту область, в которой у меня один из самых больших пробелов в навыке программирования. Поэтому скромно предположу, что дело может быть в наличии * у buffer. Без неё получается вот так:

<0610>

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработало!

Comment: Ну и хорошо. Я переделал комментарий в ответ. Примите его, чтобы придать этому вопросу логическую завершённость.

Answer (score 4):

Могу ошибаться, но: 
`const unsigned char *buffer[]={0x06,0x10};` это массив со ссылками на область памяти.
`const unsigned char buffer[]={0x06,0x10};` это уже запись данных в какой либо области памяти. ссылку которой можно получить через `&buffer`

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вопрос целит ровно в ту область, в которой у меня один из самых больших пробелов в навыке программирования. Поэтому скромно предположу, что дело может быть в наличии * у buffer. Без неё получается вот так:

```
<0610>
```